# Forcing filter execution in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Is there a way to force a (query) filter to be executed for every query irrespective of whether or not it is present in the search query request?  In my case, I have a native search script which is used to filter documents based on a dynamically changing list which is maintained outside of the elasticsearch instance.  Since I do not control all the clients which query the server, I can't guarantee that they will do the filtering properly or add a reference to the script in the request and would therefore like to force the filter execution within the ES server itself.  Is this (easily) achievable?  (I am using ES 1.7.0/2.0)

TIA

Comment: [filtered aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#filtered)  might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If users can submit arbitrary *requests* to the cluster, then there is absolutely nothing that you can do to stop them from doing whatever they want to do.

You really only have two options here:

1. If users can select arbitrary queries/filters, but you control the index or indices that they go too, then you can use [filtered aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#filtered) to limit what they can see.
2. Use Shield (not free) to prevent arbitrary access to limit what indices/aliases any given request can access (with aliases using filters to hide data).

Answer (score 0):

[Aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html#filtered) are definitely the way to go. Create an alias per client if you need a different filter per client and ask him to talk to that alias.